# OpenCV's elementwise multiplication gives unexpected value

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have two 2x7 matrices `A` and `B`, while the top left elements of them are `5` and `3`. I did a elementwise multiplication and the result is a 2x7 matrix `C`. But I didn't get `15` for the top left element of `C`. Instead, I got `0`. Where did I get wrong? In the command line I used `g++ -o main main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -L/usr/include/opencv`. Thank you in advance for help.

**main.cpp** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    cv:Mat A(2,7,CV_64FC1);
    Mat B(2,7,CV_64FC1);
    Mat C;
    A.at<float>(0,0) = 5;
    B.at<float>(0,0) = 3;
    C = A.mul(B);

    cout<<C.at<float>(0,0)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `C.at<float>(0,0)` --- since both `A` and `B` are `CV_64FC1`, so is the result. Hence, you should access it with `at<double>`. Right now you're reading only half of the bits of the 64bit floating point value... garbage would be the expected result of doing so. | In fact you're also setting `A` and `B` to garbage to begin with, since the same mistake happens there.

Comment: Thanks! I changed all `CV_64FC1` to `CV_32FC1` (while I keep all the `at<float>`), and it works!